# Select multiple accumulates data, how to clean it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, forms

Help, I have a form that is automatically filled with data when I select a customer, and that includes their addresses, the addresses are loaded into a select multiple. The problem is this: when i select another customer the form is not completely cleaned, either the address to previous customer as address to current customer are accumulated in select multiple. Is it possible automatically clean the entire form or at least the select multiple when selecting another customer? Thanks.

```
$('input[name=\'customer\']').catcomplete({
 minLength: 0, delay: 100,
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=sale/customer/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {   
            response($.map(json, function(item) {
                return {
                    category: item['customer_group'],
                    label: item['name'],
                    value: item['customer_id'],
                    customer_group_id: item['customer_group_id'],
                    firstname: item['firstname'],
                    lastname: item['lastname'],
                    rut_cliente_id: item['rut_cliente_id'],
                    email: item['email'],
                    telephone: item['telephone'],
                    fax: item['fax'],
                    banca: item['banca'],
                    company: item['company'],
                    iban: item['iban'],
                    address: item['address']
                }
            }));
        }
    });
}, 

select:function(event,ui){
    event.preventDefault()
    $('input[name=\'customer\']').val(ui.item.label);
    $('input[name=\'customer_id\']').val(ui.item.value);
    $('input[name=\'firstname\']').val(ui.item.firstname);
    $('input[name=\'lastname\']').val(ui.item.lastname);
    $('input[name=\'rut_cliente_id\']').val(ui.item.rut_cliente_id);
    $('input[name=\'email\']').val(ui.item.email);
    $('input[name=\'telephone\']').val(ui.item.telephone);
    $('input[name=\'banca\']').val(ui.item.banca);
    $('input[name=\'iban\']').val(ui.item.iban);
    $('input[name=\'company\']').val(ui.item.company);
    $('input[name=\'fax\']').val(ui.item.fax);




    for(i in ui.item.address){ 

        html+='<option value="' + ui.item.address[i]['address_id']+'">'+ui.item.address[i]['firstname']+' ' + ui.item.address[i]['lastname']+', ' + ui.item.address[i]['address_1']+', ' + ui.item.address[i]['city']+', ' + ui.item.address[i]['country']+'</option>';
    }

    $('select[name=\'shipping_address\']').html(html);
    $('select[name=\'payment_address\']').html(html);

    $('select[id=\'customer_group_id\']').removeAttr('disabled').val(ui.item['customer_group_id']).change().attr('disabled',true); 


    return false; 

}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code before setting new values

```
$("input").each(function(){
   $(this).val("");
});
$('select[name=\'shipping_address\']').html("");
$('select[name=\'payment_address\']').html("");
html = ""
```